# Bash rename with logical-mathematical operations

Tags: linux, bash, rename, file-rename, mv

I have files with the following naming-logic .JPEG (old cameras). e.i., DSC01415.JPEG.

My riddle has been that I would like to make something like:

```
mv DSC{1415..4131}.JPEG DSC{0001..3517}.JPEG
```

Which has equal effect of, for any file:

```
mv DSC<number>.JPEG DSC<number-less-1414>.JPEG
```

Comment: Turn your riddle into scribble and paste it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
for ((i = 1415; i <= 4131; i++)); do
    oldname=$(printf "DSC%04d.JPEG" "$i")
    newname=$(printf "DSC%04d.JPEG" "$((i - 1414))")
    if [[ -f $oldname && ! -f $newname ]]; then
        echo mv -- "$oldname" "$newname"
    fi
done
```

If the output looks good, drop the `echo`.
Please make sure to **create the backup** before execution not to lose your precious pictures by accident.

Comment: This answer looks good to me. A loop such as this is basically the only way to do it in shell (without custom tools) because the `mv` command can only have one destination file or directory.

Comment: You could skip the backup by changing `mv $oldname $newname` command to `ln $oldname new/$newname`, creating hard links in a subdirectory. This will use no additional space, but keep both old and new files. If the new filenames look good, you can then delete the old files and the new ones will still be valid.

Comment: Very good. I ended up making a closh (clojure/bash interop). And, thank you for refresh the warning *backup your files!*. I had, but, as we deal with mutable objects in the shell, it's always a great reminder. I will post my solution underneath, if anyone is curious about it.

Comment: @dgc thank you for the commnet. When renaming the filenames which contain serial numbers such as dsc, we need to be careful about the overlap between original names and new names. Creating the hard links sounds a good idea but it may cause the overlap issue. We can avoid it by creating the links in the different directory.

Answer (score 0):

I ended working in a closh (clojure-shell) solution. It was fun. And, probably will be doing more some crazy stuff with it.

```clj
#!/usr/bin/env closh-zero.jar
  
(defn split-reg [filename reg] 
  (str/split filename (re-pattern reg)))

  
;; ls |> (map #(split-reg % "teste")) |> (map second) |> \
;; (map #(split-reg % ".txt")) |> (map first) |> \
;; (map # (Integer/parseInt %))
  
(defn file-ids [file reg1 reg2]
  (->
   (split-reg file reg1)
   (second)
   ((fn [s] (split-reg s reg2)))
   (first)
   ((fn [s] (Integer/parseInt s)))))

(defn clj-rn [file reg1 arg reg2]
  (sh mv (identity file) (str/join [reg1 arg reg2])))
```

In the closh shell, after defining those functions,

```clj
ls |> (map #(file-ids % "DSC" ".JPG")) |> (map #(- % 1414)) |> (map str) |> (map #(clj-rn %1 "foto" %2 ".jpg") 
(sh ls |> (identity)))
```

[image: It worked!]